# Trying to understand/get working a k-means clustering algorithem in MySQL

Tags: mysql, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am picking up MySQL for the first time and have been playing around with a location clustering algorithm for sql that I found at http://jonisalonen.com/2012/k-means-clustering-in-mysql/. I find clustering interesting and am trying to figure out how this works, but have had some trouble.

Here is the code I typed in (I have been using sqlfiddle.com)

```
create table km_data (id int primary key, cluster_id int,
    lat double, lng double);

create table km_clusters (id int auto_increment primary key,
    lat double, lng double
);


INSERT INTO km_data 
VALUES(1,0,88.3324,56.343);

INSERT INTO km_data 
VALUES(2,0,88.3324,56.342);

INSERT INTO km_data 
VALUES(3,0,83.234,54.234);

INSERT INTO km_data 
VALUES(4,0,88.33,57.234);

INSERT INTO km_data 
VALUES(5,0,88.234,86.654);

INSERT INTO km_data 
VALUES(6,0,78.673,56.854);

INSERT INTO km_data 
VALUES(7,0,83.136,46.958);


INSERT INTO km_clusters (lat, lng) SELECT lat, lng FROM km_data LIMIT 10;

UPDATE km_data d SET cluster_id = 
(SELECT id FROM km_clusters c ORDER BY POW(d.lat-c.lat,2)+POW(d.lng-c.lng,2) ASC LIMIT 1);

UPDATE km_clusters C, (SELECT cluster_id, AVG(lat) AS lat, AVG(lng) AS lng 
FROM km_data GROUP BY cluster_id) D SET C.lat=D.lat, C.lng=D.lng WHERE C.id=D.cluster_id;
```

This compiles fine, but when I put in the updating part into a loop as the website had it so it continually updates the clusters SQL fiddle complains,

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE km_data d SET cluster_id = (SELECT id FROM km_clusters c ORDER BY POW(' at line 2"

I noticed that "UNTIL" is not bolded and was wondering if that is not an appropriate term to use for loops like this:

```
 BEGIN
 UPDATE km_data d SET cluster_id = 
(SELECT id FROM km_clusters c ORDER BY POW(d.lat-c.lat,2)+POW(d.lng-c.lng,2) ASC LIMIT 1);

UPDATE km_clusters C, (SELECT cluster_id, AVG(lat) AS lat, AVG(lng) AS lng 
FROM km_data GROUP BY cluster_id) D SET C.lat=D.lat, C.lng=D.lng WHERE C.id=D.cluster_id;  

UNTIL ROW_COUNT() = 0 
END REPEAT;
```

Also, this algorithm seems like it may only work well for large amounts of data (not the couple that I have), is that correct to assume? The only time I have gotten 2 pieces of data in the same cluster, they had the same exact location. Maybe this is a wrong as I have not gotten the loop to function correctly, though I have simulated the loop by running that same block of code like 10 times in a row. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this.

It will be **many many times faster** to simply load the data into a clustering toolkit such as [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) or sklearn, cluster it there, and then load the result back into your database.

The reason is that these tools are just much better optimized for this use case. SQL databases are good for general purpose querying, but not for optimized learning algorithms.

On a side note, **don't use k-means on GPS coordinates**. K-means is a variance minimization technique. For such data, methods such as DBSCAN and OPTICS that can use Haversine distance work much better. Here are some examples:

https://doublebyteblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/20/spatial-data-mining/

this one also shows how crappy k-means results on such data are (the "giraffe" patterned image at the bottom):

http://www.vitavonni.de/blog/201410/2014102301-clustering-23-mio-tweet-locations.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will look into this.